# send_file not working - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sendfile

I have this action here :

```
def download
 send_file 'C:/Sites/solver/public/test.zip'
end
```

When I execute it from my html nothing happens and nothing is downloaded.

But here is the log it produce :

```
Started POST "/ssh/download" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-03 11:06:17 -0400
Processing by SshController#download as */*
Sent file C:/Sites/solver/public/test.zip (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Anyone can help me understand what is missing ?

Thank you!

Comment: try `send_file '/public/test.zip'`

Comment: How are you calling that action (download)?  I assume you are building a link maybe? Might be helpful to post that code.

Comment: Doesn't Windows use \ to separate file paths, rather than /?

Comment: BroiStatse, your method gives me a MissingFile : cannot read file /public/test.zip error.

Comment: if I use windows's \ it gives me MissingFile error

Comment: it can be caused by setting `x_sendfile_header` incorrectly in your environment file. can you post more info about your server? is it webrick in dev mode? do you have `x_sendfile_header` set to something in environment configuration?

Comment: Im kinda new to this. i'm using railsbrick. im using a button that call a javascript. I know nothing of x_sendfile_header

Comment: @GuillaumeCaillé It sounds like the problem is the javascript - you need to `link_to` the download action.

Answer (score 0):

In your view, add a `download` option, eg:

```
link_to 'Download', download_path(id), download: "file"
```